# Spring security bypass if has different Authorization header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented spring security with jwt and is working fine.

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomJWTProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new CustomJwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
}
```

But i have a typical use case where i get jwt token or 64bit fixed length token in Authorization header.

If it is JWT token, spring security should work as is and if it is not, the control should be passed to some method (where i have my logic to validate that token)

My filter looks like

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterchain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(myCustomValidator(authToken)){
            //if this is true it should skip spring security jwt token verification
            //which is in configure phase
        }else{
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendError(403, "Access denied");
        }
        System.out.println("authToken="+authToken);
        filterchain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

How/Where can i add this filter to bypass spring security, or any other mechanism to skip spring security based on authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OncePerRequestFilter. You need to create a class and extend this class where you override its method(doFilterInternal) and put your logic there.

You can configure that filter like below.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class YourClass extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private YourFilter authFilter;
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.addFilterAt(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Rahul Kumar, this will help me in blocking if my fixed length token fails. but if i know my fixed length token is valid, how can i skip it through spring security?